# I cannot install aws cli on mac os with pip - awscli: command not found

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, terminal, pip, aws-cli

I tried to follow this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html).

This is what I did in the console:

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade awscli
```

after that, when I write:

```
pip3 --version
```

I'm getting:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /Users/user/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

then I wrote:

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade awscli
```

this command downloaded `awscli` and automatically added this:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

to my `.profile`

Later on, just to be sure, I wrote:

```
source ~/.profile
```

and then when I type:

```
user$ aws
-bash: aws: command not found
```

I restarted the terminal with no luck also.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Have you checked whether the executables are indeed at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/`?  Since you installed with the `user scheme` (--user), I would expect that the executables should be at somewhere like `~/Library/Python/3.4/bin/` instead.

Comment: @LeoC yes, you are absolutely correct! the other path works. Do you bother to add it as an answer?

Comment: Glad that it helps.  Nah, too lazy – thanks for asking though.

Comment: The easiest way to install the AWS CLI on MacOS is with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/): ```brew install awscli```

Comment: if you have brew us: `brew install awscli brew install awsebcli`

Answer (score 125):

Here are the two steps to install AWS cli on mac OSX

### FIRST

#### Offical version

- brew install awscli

### SECOND

#### Development version

- brew install awscli --HEAD

Comment: That worked for me as well, but I don't know that "Official Version" is the correct tile, since brew isn't mentioned on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path

Comment: This would result in "Permission Denied" now. "sudo" won't work either caz it's not allowed any more.. can anyone updates?

Comment: I had Permission Denied issue as well, see my answer on what worked for me below

Comment: sheesh, why don't they just say this in the aws documentation!

Answer (score 69):

When "**pip3 install**" is called with the "**--user**" option, it installs the aws executable in a user-specific location.  This can be one of many possible locations, but the best way to find out where is with this command:

**python3 -m site --user-base**

On my system, this returned:

- **/Users/[myusername]/Library/Python/3.6**

This directory has a "bin" subdirectory, and that is where the "aws" executable was located.

I figured this out from following:

- pip3 install --help
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-contents

Comment: Have sent a feedback on the aws documentation link - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path. Hopefully it would be corrected soon.

Comment: dovetails with https://github.com/rajivkanaujia/alphaworks/wiki/Installing-AWS-CLI-via-pip3-and-python3, but can't upvote his answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me when using `pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user` since my `.local` never created a `bin` subdirectory.

Answer (score 27):

Simple do these three steps:

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip 
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Comment: Worked for me on Centos 7, used it as workaround for pip install --user --upgrade awscli => aws => aws: command not found. Also found an official docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html

Comment: Neither pip, nor brew worked. Got all sorts of errors. this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 14):

`brew install awscli` should work

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me, I experienced permission issues and had to create a local Frameworks folder first before running brew install. using macOS High Sierra

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks
sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local/Frameworks
brew install awscli
```

Comment: Simply running `sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks` (no `chown`) worked for me. macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Answer (score 4):

To answer the original question about installing using pip:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo easy_install nose
sudo easy_install tornado
sudo easy_install six
sudo pip install --ignore-installed awscli
```

worked for me on Mojave

Comment: Worked for me. `brew install awscli` was giving me a hard time, this is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error, when trying to install **awscli**. I was following steps mentioned here by amazon [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html]

I use anaconda, so when I was using `pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user`
it installs awscli in `/Users/username/.local/lib/python3.6/`

So, I used following to update awscli to anaconda-

`conda install -c conda-forge awscli`

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following commands to install awscli :

$ curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
$ unzip awscli-bundle.zip
$ ./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws

check version using : `/Users/xxx/bin/aws --version`
configure using : `/Users/xxx/bin/aws configure`

Answer (score 0):

Was facing a similar issue. Resolved it by installing python 3.9 using brew install.

> brew install python@3.9

Then reinstall awscli

Answer (score -1):

I followed the below steps and it works for MacOS 10.11

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
```

Unzip the package.

```
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
```

And instead of given command:

```
'sudo /usr/local/bin/python2.7 awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws'
```

which is broken due to pip, I think, I used the below command and it worked for me.

```
python3.6 ./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
```